# Successfully inserting data into Mysql database in python, data not readable in python or accessible in popsql

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database

I created a database with 3 (2 relevant) tables:
player_table
teams
results_table

Then I successfully connected to mysql using mysql connector. I was also able to successfully execute an insert query.  I only know this because if I try to run the insert function again, it tells me that the primary key is already in use.

However, when I SELECT * from teams (or player_table), I get no results either in pycharm or from popsql.

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error
import pandas as pd


def create_server_connection(host_name, user_name, user_password, db_name):
    connection = None
    try:
        connection = mysql.connector.connect(
            host=host_name,
            user=user_name,
            passwd=user_password,
            database=db_name
        )
        print("MySQL Database connection successful")
    except Error as err:
        print(f"Error: '{err}'")

    return connection


connection = create_server_connection('localhost', 'root', '!DerW95!', 'Pitcher_Batter_Results')

query = 'INSERT INTO teams VALUES(01, "Mariners", "Seattle");'
query_two = 'SELECT * FROM player_table;'
query_three = 'INSERT INTO player_table VALUES(01, "Jarred Kelenic", "OF", 01);'

def execute_query(connection, query):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    try:
        cursor.execute(query)
        connection.commit()
        print("Query successful")
    except Error as err:
        print(f"Error: '{err}'")


def read_query(connection, query):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    result = None
    try:
        cursor.execute(query)
        result = cursor.fetchall()
        return result
    except Error as err:
        print(f"Error: '{err}'")


execute_query(connection, query_three)
read_query(connection, query_two)
```

I was expecting to get some kind of result back from my read function or at minimum find the inserted data with popsql.

Comment: It seems like your code doesn't do anything to the results of the select.

Comment: I see.  I set a var = to read query and printed var.  Not sure why it doesn't show in popsql when I run the select statement though
EDIT: I was connected to the wrong database in popsql